# Run command every 30 minutes in thread on Android service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have an Android service running within my app in the background, this service runs several threads, one of which is meant to run a command ever 30 minutes.

```
Thread InternetThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1800000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("test", "We are running");
                    runCommand();
            }
        }
    };
```

However what I have found is this code will not always run every 30 minutes, some times it can be up to an hour between runs, never less than 30 minutes but can be more. I assume this has something to do with the service being pursed by Android?
But I am not really sure as this is at the limited of my understanding with Android services and threads.

Hopefully someone can help with a way to make sure the "runCommand()" does actually run exactly every 30 minutes.

Comment: 3600000/1000/60 = 60 minutes?

Comment: yes my bad should be 1800000 had writen out the code I am using 1800000 and getting random results

Comment: @Lestat 1800000 is correct.

Comment: use scheduleAtFixedRate of ExcutorService

Comment: @ZacPowell If you implement Thread or HandlerThread, be sure that your UI thread does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete—do not call Thread.wait() or Thread.sleep(). Using thread.sleep() inside a thread is bad design. developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html. Use a ExecutorService as suggested by blackbelt. Alaram Manager can also be a good to use

Comment: @Raghunandan could you show an example for using one of these methods?

Comment: This isn't how you do it. Use AlarmManager setRepeating() to guarantee that it executes in every 30 minutes. And if you want it to happen lets say on 15 and 45 minutes past every hour, set triggerAtMillis.

Answer (score 0):

The process may be freezing, try this:

```
Thread InternetThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        long endtime = 0;
        while (true) {
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800000;
            while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.i("test", "We are running");
            runCommand();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: If you implement Thread or HandlerThread, be sure that your UI thread does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete—do not call Thread.wait() or Thread.sleep(). Using thread.sleep() inside a thread is bad design. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html